# Finding minor of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Given the following matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\ 
 8 & 5 & 8 & t \\ 
 2 & 1 & 6 & 6
\end{pmatrix} $$
I am looking for the matrix rank depending on the parameter t.
I have the information that minor formed by last three columns is equal to $11(16-t)$. Thus for $t\ne 16 $, $r(A)=3$. How this minor was calculated also i am not sure wheter i fully understand the definition of minor.

Comment: A minor is a determinant.

Comment: thus i have to look for det of matrix formed by last three columsn of matrix i have posted?

Comment: Exactly. But my suggestion is that generally we use elementary (row) transformations which lead to the RREF to find the rank of a matrix, rather than calculating the minors.

Comment: By inspection the rank of the matrix is at least two, whatever value $t$ may have.  For example the first and last rows (which don't depend on $t$) are clearly linearly independent.  So your work is reduced to considering the case $t=16$, which is the only possibility the rank can be as small as two.

Comment: the third column is $11$ times the first minus $16$ times the second, so you can throw that out when computing the rank. in fact you can throw away any one of the first three columns.

Answer (score 1):

as i said in the comment, we can throw away the first column. we can compute the rank of $\pmatrix{2&1&5\\5&8&t\\1&6&6}\to 
\pmatrix{1&6&6\\2&1&5\\5&8&t} \to
\pmatrix{1&6&6\\0&-11&-7\\0&-22&t-30} \to
\pmatrix{1&6&6\\0&-11&-7\\0&0&t-16} $

so the rank of the original matrix if $ 3$ if and only if $t \neq 16$ and is $2$ otherwise.